# manipulate xml using perl or sed

Tags: xml, perl, sed

Input line:

```
<column name="Sample"><![TEST[x-y]]></column>
```

Output line:

```
<column name="Sample"><![TEST[y]]></column>
```

`x` is any number

`y` is any number

I want to get rid of `x-`.
How to do it in Perl? Or maybe it's possible with sed?

Comment: did you try parsing the input? This is not XML, specifically `<![TEST[y]]>` is not well-formed XML. So you probably shouldn't call it XML (and of course you can't use XML tools on it).

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do want you want:

```
$line=~s/(?<=<\!\[TEST\[)\d+\-//;
```

One-liner flavor:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=<\!\[TEST\[)\d+\-//' file.xml
```

But, as [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg) in StackOverflow, avoid parsing/processing XML with the use of regular expressions. Use instead a module (eg. [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm)).

Comment: *Please* don't recommend `XML::Simple`. Its own documentation says this *"The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces."*

Comment: Noted. It has been a long time since I had to parse any XML. Please feel free to edit my answer with more appropriate modules.